# Three.js map keeps rotating and not smooth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js

I am starting to learn Three.js, while reading through the docs, watching videos etc, I am trying to make a basic copy of the http://habbox.game/navigator NFT website.

As I said I am still a beginner, but I already ran into my first two problems. I have tried to create a 'map' with a lot of colored squares on it.

I would like those squares to be moveable using the right mouse button. This already seems to be possible using the OrbitControls, but the map is also rotating.

Second problem is that the movements are not smooth at all. If I compare this with the HabboX navigator, the difference is extremely big.

I have created the map using the following code (in a Next.js project):

I tried to set orbit controls 'enable' property to false to disable some movements and only use the enablePan property. This didn't seem to change much. Setting enableRotate to false didn't do much either.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

export default function Map() {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let scene: THREE.Scene;
    let camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
    let renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
    let controls: OrbitControls;

    const init = () => {
      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
      camera.position.z = 5;

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      if (canvasRef.current && canvasRef.current.children.length === 0) {
        canvasRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      }

      controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.enabled = false;
      controls.enablePan = true;
      controls.enableRotate = false;

      const pixelSize = 0.1;
      const gridSize = 100;
      const pixels: THREE.Mesh[] = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i += 1) {
        for (let j = 0; j < gridSize; j += 1) {
          const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
          const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff });
          const pixel = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
          pixel.position.set((i * pixelSize) - ((gridSize * pixelSize) / 2), (j * pixelSize) - ((gridSize * pixelSize) / 2), 0);
          pixels.push(pixel);
          scene.add(pixel);
        }
      }

      animate();
    };

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    init();

    return () => {
      if (renderer) {
        renderer.dispose();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={canvasRef} />;
}
```

Comment: 1. [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=orbit#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) only affects the `Camera`, for drag and drop interaction there is a [DragControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/DragControls) [Example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=drag#misc_controls_drag).
2. Your code is not optimised, there are 2 axes to explore to optimise your code:
- The first one would be to reused the same material and geometry for each mesh;
- The second one will need more abstract comprehension and more reading, `instancing`.